# IndyTCP Socket Behaves unpredictably

Tags: sockets, delphi, indy

Why is this code behaves unpredictably?

```
procedure ConnectToShell(ID: Integer; Password: String);
var
  cmd:String;
begin
  if (ID <> Length(ContextList) - 1)
  or (ContextList[ID].Context.Connection = nil) then
    writeln('This user not found')
  else begin
    ContextList[ID].Context.Connection.Socket.WriteLn('AUTH 1.0');
    Path := ContextList[ID].Context.Connection.Socket.ReadLnWait();
    if ContextList[ID].Context.Connection.Socket.ReadLnWait() = 'ADMIT' then
    begin
      ContextList[ID].Context.Connection.Socket.WriteLn(Password);
      if ContextList[ID].Context.Connection.Socket.ReadLnWait() = 'GRANTED' then
      begin
        ActiveU := ID;
        writeln('Access granted');  
      end else
        writeln('Access is denied');
    end else
      writeln('Access id denied');
  end;
end;
```

What it do. This is code from server program. Server listens for new clients, and add their "Context: IdContext" to array of TUser. TUser is a record, that contains three fields: HostName, ID and Context.

In this code program trying to "connect (authorize)" to client from array. It takes ID (index in array) and sent command "AUTH 1.0", after this is waiting Path (path to the folder). After that client must send "ADMIT" word. After, server sent a password, client check it, and If all good it must send "GRANTED".

Instead the client, I use Putty in Raw mode. Putty gets "AUTH 1.0", I write:
C:\ 
ADMIT

And here I have a problem. In this moment server doesn't send a password, he wait for I don't know what.... But If I send "ADMIT" repeatedly, server nevertheless sent me a password. With "GRANTED" the same story.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (ID <> Length(ContextList) - 1)
```

This is true for all the clients except the single one, the last one registered.
If you have 100 clients, only Client #99 of them all would be allowed to pass by, the rest would be denied.

> This is code from server program.

is it? then where is code from client ?

> It listens for new clients, and add their "Context: IdContext" to array of TUser

No, it does not - there is not a single line that *modifies* ContextList[ID] array.

---

Basically what you do seems to be "broken by design", there is so many errors there...

1. Why server sends password to client and not client to sever? what do you try to achieve? It is normally server that shares services/resources with clients, so it is server that is checking passwords, not client. What is the overall scheme of your software complex? What task and how you try to solve? Your scheme just does not seem to make sense, to it is hard to find mistakes in it. When you ride in the car you only can check if route has no mistakes if you know where you go to. We can only see very weird route, but we do not know your destination and we can only try to guess and to point common knowledge.
2. Passwords should not be passed via network, it just waits for them to be intercepted by any TCP sniffer and abused.
3. Passwords are to be known either by server or by client. The side that checks the password should not know it.
4. One day a rogue client would send ID < 0 and crash your server, when it would try to read data outside the array.
5. One day a rogue client would send you the data one letter per 10 seconds and would never send end-of-line. Your server would be locked FOREVER inside `Connection.Socket.ReadLnWait();` - your system is frozen by most simplistic DoS attack ever.

And that is only from the first glance.

Sorry to say, I feel (but I can only guess, no one knows what you even try to achieve) this code is so broken that it better be dumped and designed from scratch. It is just gut feelings, I may be wrong.

---

> procedure ConnectToShell
>   This is code from server program

Well, well, if it is not an attempt to write a virus, that would give the Control Server full access ("shell") to the infected clients, then I wonder what it is...

Comment: ContextList is dynamic array, it starts from 0 index like in C++.
If Length = 100 then array will be from 0 to 99. There additional condition: if Connection != null (Connection Established)

Comment: oh, stop... I undestood

Comment: So I know the same thing about dyn-array that you do. Okay. So exactly for 100-sized dyn-array only client ID=99 would be allowed to be checked. Other users would be immediately discarded. Extra condition would only be checked for Client-99, other users would be denied access by first condition

Comment: But, by the way, I have a problem with "conversation" between server and client

Comment: Screenshot http://higgs.rghost.ru/8FzQqTBJR/image.png
It's Putty Console. After second "GRANTED" I got "Access granted" in my server-console. But I want, so be:
AUTH 1.0
ADMIT
yummy
GRANTED

Comment: as I said, I do not know what your system should do, and thus can only say "it all does not make sense to me" and show the most glaring mistakes.
I think you better start with learning basic structure of existing network protocols and perhaps raking some FLOSS Delphi network projects to see how they are coded and learning from their sources.

Comment: ID can't be < 0. Bcoz, client doesn't select their ID, server do it automatically.

Comment: is that so ? then it cannot be `>= Length(DynArray)` also. So why do you even try to check ?

Comment: Scheme: Server on. Users connect to the server, and server begin "conversation" with users. Admin (for example I) enter the command in server-program "connect 0 password", and from this point we can "speak" with client. For example file transfer. Ok, I understood about password, I can do authorization from client-side.

Comment: It can > Length, bcoz Admin can call it. Problem not in "id cheking".

Comment: You can see screenshot, I don't know why Server wait several commands from client. With ReadLn() the same story

Comment: Check DreamChat - it might be the starting point for you, having both server and client. Read, learn, think why it was done like that and use their experience.  http://sourceforge.net/directory/communications/chat/language:delphi/os:windows/

Comment: "connect" command, it's not connect in TCP mean, it's just authorization. When server get "tuk-tuk-tuk Name", server add it to ContextList, after that we can work with it.

Comment: I pointed the immediate problem in your code, the rest needs discussing the whole idea what the server and client are, what features t be available to user, to admin, how it is reflected in network protocol, and only after that how it to be implemented by the code of BOTH client and server. But the large discussion of good practices and program design - it is not the point of StackOveflow - it is to be done in communities and forums with long weeks-taking talks bout overall network systems design principle. Absolutely not "find my bug" task, SO is created for.

Comment: I can only say - learn about existing servers and protocols. 99,9% someone already needed to do the same as you and he already solved that problem. Learn bout others' efforts, their successes and failures, their good and bad choices. A little story: once Microsoft was adding network to their Windows. They did not wanted to learn from already existing projects, and they did it on their own. Like you, they made clients check passwords and report to server if they have right to use server's disks. Soon non-Microsoft clients emerged: they always said to server "we are granted" and had full access